# Convert json to csv with seperate headers for each key of JSON object

Tags: node.js, json, express, csv

Suppose my JSON object that needs to be converted looks like this,is there way i can convert it to a csv file which follows the format specified in in the image attached below:

```
const inputData = {
   keyOne: [{
    keyOneColOne: 1345,
    keyOneColTwo: 546,
    keyOneColThree: 769
  }],
  keyTwo: [
    {
      keyTwoColOne: 1,
      keyTwoColTwo: 2,
      keyTwoColThree: 2,
      keyTwoColFour: 1
    },
    {
      keyTwoColOne: 1,
      keyTwoColTwo: 2,
      keyTwoColThree: 2,
      keyTwoColFour: 1
    }
  ],
  keyThree: [
    {
      keyThreeColOne: 22,
      keyThreeColTwo: 23,
      keyThreeColThree: 24,
      keyThreeColFour: 25
    },
    {
      keyThreeColOne: 22,
      keyThreeColTwo: 23,
      keyThreeColThree: 24,
      keyThreeColFour: 25
    }
  ]
}
```

So is there any way to produce output in the format given below(in Node-express),
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

This gives you a method (`parseAsync`) that returns a string

```
const { parseAsync } = require('json2csv');

....

let csvString = await parseAsnyc(myJson);
```

Since you are wanting to separate the json by keys in the csv file, you can just parse each part of the json separately and then add it on to the csv string.

For example:

```
const { parseAsync } = require('json2csv');

...

async function parseMyData(inputData) {
      let csv = "";
      
      // for every object in 'inputData' array, we'll parse and add to csv string and add line breaks
      for (const key of inputData) {
         csv += await parseAsync(key);
         csv += "\n\n"; // add line breaks
      }

      return csv;   
}
```